# Splitting video in multiple episodes with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to cut one video into multiple pieces with `ffmpeg`.

When I cut just one episode

```
ffmpeg -i 001.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:00:25.500 -strict -2 out1.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i 001.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:25.500 -t 00:00:33.750 -strict -2 out2.mp4
```

my video is cut instantaneously.

But when I chain markers where I'd like to cut

```
ffmpeg -i 001.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:00:25.500 -strict -2 out1.mp4 -ss 00:00:25.500 -t 00:00:33.750 -strict -2 out2.mp4
```

it still works, but it takes considerably more time (about 10 sec), and I see the same output as when I convert something.

Is something wrong with my `ffmpeg-command`, or it is better to execute `ffmpeg-commands` one by one?

Comment: Don't reask, it will be better long term if you just let moderator;s migrate it.  I have already flagged it, but if it gets closed without moving, just flag it yourself and ask a mod to move it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ffmpeg is probably re-encoding `out2.mp4` because you did not include your copy options for your second output:

```
ffmpeg -i 001.mp4 -codec copy -t 00:00:25.5 out1.mp4 -codec copy -ss 00:00:25.5 -t 00:00:33.75 out2.mp4
```

- `-strict -2` is not required in this case. If you are re-encoding, and no other AAC encoders are available, then ffmpeg will use `-codec:a aac` which requires `-strict -2` (or the alias `-strict experimental` which I prefer).
- `-codec copy` will copy all streams of each type if present. For MP4 that usually just means audio and video, but other containers can have subtitles or even a data stream.
- You do not need to use `-ss` if the value is 0.

Comment: Exactly what I need!